# To compile XML syntax, the scala.xml package must be on the classpath

Tags: scala, sbt, spray

I am getting error:

> Error:(9, 12) To compile XML syntax, the scala.xml package must be on
>   the classpath.

Please see (https://github.com/scala/scala-xml) for details.

Kindly help on this:

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
object SbtDemo extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
path("hello") {
  get {
    complete {
      <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559236/object-xml-is-not-a-member-of-package-scala

Comment: Cross posted here: https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/issues/79